# "Remember Me" in Spring Security

Tags: spring, cookies, spring-security, remember-me

I want to use "Remember-me" functionality in spring security to enable a user to keep logged-in. In my application I provide a checkbox to the user to select remember-me and if the user checks it then after successful login, spring application sends a remember-me cookie to the browser.
I have three fields: Username, Password and Code. I want to keep these fields to loggef-in.

This is the configuration in secuirty.xml:

```
<security:http auto-config="true" use-expressions="true">
.....
.....
<security:remember-me remember-me-cookie="rvm-track-rm" remember-me- 
parameter="remember-me" token-repository-ref="tokenRepository" token- 
validity-seconds="864000" key="rvm-track-web-html" user-service- 
ref="userDetailsServiceImpl"/>
.....
.....
```

```
<bean id="tokenRepository" class="org.springframework.security.web.
authentication.rememberme.InMemoryTokenRepositoryImpl"/>    

<bean id="requestContextFilter" class="org.springframework.web.
filter.RequestContextFilter"/>

<bean id="shaPasswordEncoder" class="org.springframework.security.
authentication.encoding.ShaPasswordEncoder"
<constructor-arg value="512" />
</bean>

<bean id="authenticationSuccessHandler" 
class="com.revomon.tracking.web.html.SuccessfulAuthenticationHandler"/>

<security:authentication-manager>
<security:authentication-provider user-service-ref="userDetailsServiceImpl"/>
</security:authentication-manager>
```

And this the "UserDetailsServiceImpl" class:

```
@Override
    @Transactional(readOnly = true)
    public UserDetails loadUserByUsername(final String userName) throws UsernameNotFoundException {
        logger.debug("Authenticate username {}", userName);
        ServletRequestAttributes attr = (ServletRequestAttributes) RequestContextHolder.currentRequestAttributes();
        String customerCode = (String) attr.getRequest().getParameter("customer_code");
        TrackAdminUser user = userDao.findByUsernameAndCustomerCode(userName, customerCode);
        return new WebUser(user);
    }
```

My problem is that only Username and Password fields are kept and sent to remember-me. Please what is missing to kept also the code field?

Answer (score 0):

You need to sent http parameter with name appropriate your configuration - remember-me-parameter="remember-me" in your login form, in your case it "remember-me". You can add the next code to you login form:

```
<div class="checkbox">
      <label><input class="checkbox" type="checkbox" name="remember-me">Remember me</label>
</div>
```

Comment: I have already this im my login form: "<span class="icheck-inline">
                        <input type="checkbox" id="remember-me" name="remember-me" data-switchery data-switchery-color="#135673" />
                        <label for="switch_demo_2" class="inline-label"><fmt:message key="login.rememberme" /></label>
                    </span>" . But the "code" field still doesn't kept.